# How do I get generics to work with return values that require careful casting?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

I've got some data access layer code calls a stored proc and returns scalar values of various datatypes.  The syntax is ExecuteDecimal, ExecuteString, etc.  I want it to be `Execute<string>` or `Execute<decimal>`

I try this implementation and I can't compile, unless I'm doing casting using "(T) value", if I try to check the type and call a method to do the casting, no such luck.

**UPDATED  question**
Why do I have to convert to object before converting to T?

**UPDATED code**

```
internal T Execute<T>(string storedProcName, Hashtable parameters)
{
      //Next lines do compile (thanks to suggestions from answers!)
      if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
          return (T) (object) ExecuteScalar(storedProcName, parameters).ToString();
      else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
          return (T)(object) Convert.ToInt32(ExecuteScalar(storedProcName, parameters));
      //Next line compiles, but not all things boxed in an object can
      //be converted straight to type T (esp db return values that might contain DbNull.Value, etc)
      return (T)ExecuteScalar(storedProcName, parameters);
}
```

Comment: hey I am really worried. first three answers (with highest votes) are either with errors or bloated with unneeded code.

Comment: @Andrey, welcome to SO =(    I'm just disappointed I don't get to learn about 'careful casting'.  I was so excited when I read the title. =)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = ExecuteScalar(storedProcName, parameters);
if(Convert.IsDBNull(result))
    return default(T);
if(result is T) // just unbox
    return (T)result;
else            // convert
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T));
```

**Updated**: fixed DBNull handling

Comment: Interesting, It looks like ChangeType supports only things that support IConvertable.  I'd never seen that technique before.  Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewMartin all primitive types support it. But this method is not good because max didn't check for DBNull

Comment: that's better now! un-downvoting

Comment: fails if you have nullable results convert to other type, eg int?->uint? fails to change type

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof(T) == typeof(string)
```

and for null value check against `DBNull.Value`

overall method:

```
internal T Execute<T>(string storedProcName, Hashtable parameters)
{
      object res = ExecuteScalar(storedProcName, parameters);
      if (Convert.IsDBNull(res))
         return default(T); //or handle somehow
      return (T)Convert.ChangeType(res, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: @Andrey - that won't compile.

Comment: You didn't check that! But thanks anyhow, it set me down the right road and I think I got it.  I've updated my question with the new code.

Comment: Actually, I did check your code in the compiler to see if your way would work, because it was definitely cleaner than doing typeof(T). But sadly, it's required.  Downvote removed :).

Comment: @dcp I always confuse those types comparisons without IDE

Comment: @MatthewMartin check the edit. i don't have IDE by hand to check that it works but i think it should :)

Answer (score 1):

try the 'as' keyword

```
object o = ExecuteScalar(storedProcName, parameters);
string s;
int i;
// .. more

if ((s = o as string) != null)
{
  return s;
}
if ((i = o as int?) != null) // can't use as for value types, so use nullable
{
  return Convert.ToInt32(o);
}
return o as T;
```

Comment: Convert.ChangeType does all the stuff for you. and you don't check for DBNull

Comment: No.  The 'as' keyword isn't valid for value types.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your function might instead be altered to allow the object conversion function to be passed in:

```
internal T Execute<T>(string storedProcName, Hashtable parameters, Func<object, T> resultConverter)
{
}
```

Then you could create overloads for the ones you know about:

```
internal string ExecuteForString(string storedProcName, Hashtable parameters)
{
    return Execute(storedProcName, parameters, (o) => o.ToString());
}

internal int ExecuteForInt(string storedProcName, Hashtable parameters)
{
     return Execute(storedProcName, parameters, Convert.ToInt32);
}
```

In the case of your DBNull checks, you could either return `default(T)` or you could add another overload to pass in a default value if DBNull is returned - e.g. in the case of an int it might be better to get back -1 instead of 0.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot overload on return types, the argument types need to differ in type and/or number.

Comment: Interesting I've never seen default(T) of T before I think I will use that.  Remove that part that won't compile so I can upvote your answer.

Comment: Have renamed functions to avoid compilation issues since I think that's preferred rather than ending up with a case of a type that you can't resolve for the caller...