# Can I consolidate this in a generic method?

Tags: c#

I have a DataAccessBase class with the following 2 data access methods. One for ExecuteScalar and one for ExecuteNonQuery. Is it possible to consolidate it into one generic method or is even worth worrying about?

```
    protected static int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand command)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            command.Connection.Open();

            int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return result;
        }
    }

    protected static string ExecuteScalar(SqlCommand command)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            command.Connection.Open();

            string result = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            return result;
        }
    }

    private static DataTable GetDT(int id)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
        {
            string query = "select id, userid, name from tasks where id = @id";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            //Parameterized query to prevent injection attacks
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: They don't do the same thing, and what is the purpose of the `SqlDataAdapter`?

Comment: good point and eyes!

Comment: Ask yourself how you are going to pass parameters and datatypes to those when needed

Comment: I would change ExecuteScalar to be generic, how do you know it's always returning a string?

Comment: These methods are calling two different methods on SqlCommand. Not sure would you make generics out of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can definitely avoid the current repetition you've got with a generic method, but I wouldn't try to reduce it to a single method. Here's what I'd *potentially* do:

```
protected static int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand command) =>
    ExecuteCommand(command, cmd => cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());

protected static string ExecuteScalar(SqlCommand command) =>
    ExecuteCommand(command, cmd => cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

private static T ExecuteCommand<T>(SqlCommand command, Func<SqlCommand, T> resultRetriever)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Connection.Open();
        return resultRetriver(command);
    }
}
```

For the `DataTable` one, following the same pattern you'd create the command first:

```
protected static DataTable GetDataTable(SqlCommand command) =>
    ExecuteCommand(cmd =>
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        da.FillTable(table);
        return table;
    });
```

Comment: so I had SqlDataAdapter in another method that does a SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(); da.Fill(dataTable);

Comment: @Rod: So that's doing something different, and we can't tell whether or not that could use this method without seeing more details.

Comment: @JonSkeet Wouldn't it be worth adding an `Action<SqlCommand> commandInitializer` parameter so that we can create the command and dispose it inside these methods?

Comment: @vc74: Not with the code that's been given to us so far, which couldn't use that - we don't know whether the OP *wants* to dispose the passed-in command. I'd be reluctant to overgeneralize without extra information.

Comment: @JonSkeet True, it just looks weird to me to create the command first and then the connection but it's probably me getting old fashioned ;) Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what's being asked of me at this point. I thought 'using' takes care of disposing things?

Comment: @Rod: vc74 was suggesting an extra feature, but I don't think it's required. But if you want data adapter access, you'd need to provide more information - we can't help with a method we haven't seen.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, I updated the OP with how I was using the SqlDataAdapter

Comment: FYI: I've updated my answer to include a `ExecuteToDataTable` method using @JonSkeet's example logic above... hopefully that's useful?

Comment: I've updated my answer too, in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the ExecuteScalar to a generic method, allowing you to change the return type.

```
public T ExecuteScalar<T>(SqlCommand command)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command); //not needed...
        command.Connection.Open();
        var result = command.ExecuteScalar();

        //rather than just returning result with an implicit cast, use Max's trick from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2976427/361842
        if (Convert.IsDbNull(result))
            return default(T); //handle the scenario where the returned value is null, but the type is not nullable (or remove this to have such scenarios throw an exception)
        if (result is T)
            return (T)result;
        else
            (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

The logic is different in this method to in the `ExecuteNonQuery` function though, so you cannot have both represented by the same method.

---

## Update

Regarding your question about the data table, I've taken and adapted [@JonSkeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49308801/361842) to allow the class to also handle data tables:

```
public class SqlDatabaseThing //: ISqlDatabaseThing
{

    // ... additional code here ... //

    public int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand command, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new[]{}) =>
        ExecuteNonQuery(_connStr, command, sqlParameters);
    public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string connectionString, SqlCommand command, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new[]{}) =>
        ExecuteCommand(connectionString, command, cmd => cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());

    public T ExecuteScalar(SqlCommand command, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new[]{}) =>
        ExecuteScalar(_connStr, command, sqlParameters);
    public static T ExecuteScalar(string connectionString, SqlCommand command, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new[]{}) =>
        ExecuteCommand(connectionString, command, cmd => ConvertSqlCommandResult(cmd.ExecuteScalar()));

    public DataTable ExecuteToDataTable(SqlCommand command, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new[]{}) =>
        ExecuteToDataTable(_connStr, command, sqlParameters);
    public static DataTable ExecuteToDataTable(string connectionString, SqlCommand command, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new[]{}) =>
        ExecuteCommand(connectionString, command, cmd => PopulateDataTable(cmd));


    private static T ExecuteCommand<T>(string connectionString, SqlCommand command, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> sqlParameters, Func<SqlCommand, T> resultRetriever)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters);
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.Connection.Open();
            return resultRetriver(command);
        }
    }

    private static DataTable PopulateDataTable(SqlCommand command)
    {
        var da = SqlDataAdapter(command);
        var dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

    private static T ConvertSqlCommandResult(object result)
    {
        if (Convert.IsDbNull(result))
            return default(T); 
        if (result is T)
            return result as T;
        (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T));
    }

}
```

NB: In your code you'd included logic related to getting specific tasks.  That should be kept separate from your generic database logic (i.e. as presumably you'll want to return data tables for various queries, and don't want to have to rewrite your `GetDT` code each time).  As such I've provided additional sample code below showing how you could separate that logic into another class...

```
public class TaskRepository //: IRepository<Task>
{
    ISqlDatabaseThing db;
    public TaskRepository(ISqlDatabaseThing db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    readonly string GetByIdCommand = "select id, userid, name from tasks where id = @id";
    readonly string GetByIdCommandParameterId = "@id"
    readonly SqlDbType GetByIdCommandParameterIdType = SqlDbType.BigInt;
    public Task GetById(long id)
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand(GetByIdCommand);
        var parameters = IEnumerableHelper.ToEnumerable<SqlParameter>(new SqlParameter(GetByIdCommandIdParameter, GetByIdCommandIdParameterType, id));
        var dataTable = db.ExecuteToDataTable(command, parameters);
        return DataTableToTask(dataTable)[0];
    }
    private IEnumerable<Task> DataTableToTask(DataTable dt)
    {
        foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
        {
            yield return DataRowToTask(row);
        }
    }
    private Task DataRowToTask (DataRow dr)
    {
        return new Task()
        {
            Id = dr["Id"]
            ,Name = dr["Name"]
            ,UserId = dr["UserId"]
        };
    }

}

public static class IEnumerableHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(params T[] parameters)
    {
        return parameters;
    } 
}
```

NB: This code is untested; any issues please let me know.